# Overriding SASS variables inside create-react-app

Tags: sass, create-react-app, node-sass

So i'm using create-react-app, and am importing a custom component:

component.js:

```
import './component.scss'
```

component.scss:

```
$primary-color: black;
```

demo.js:

```
import Component from './Components/component.js'
import './demo.scss'
...
render() => {
  return <Component />
}
```

and in demo.scss:

```
$primary-color: red;
```

I would expect that the component would be rendered using $primary-color as red, but it keeps as black.

I also tried importing demo.scss before importing Component
so, in demo.js:

```
import './demo.scss'
import Component from './Components/component.js'
```

but i'm getting the same result

Answer (score 1):

SASS uses top-down compilation, so it reads top-down and will compile css with whatever variable values it has at the time it gets to those lines in the scss files.

So in the first example with `demo.scss` imported after `component.scss`, the css for `component.scss` will compile first using the value it had at that time for `$primary-color`. Once it gets to `demo.scss`, the value changes, but the css for the component was already compiled with the old value.

Therefore, the second order is correct for overriding default variable values.

```
import './demo.scss'
import Component from './Components/component.js'
```

However, the issue becomes that the line in `component.scss` where `$primary-color: black;` will override the red color. So here, we can use the `!default` flag, which means "Only default to black if no previous value for `$primary-color` has been previously defined."

```
$primary-color: black !default;
```

More info on [`!default`](https://anotheruiguy.gitbooks.io/sassintherealworld_book-i/handy-tools/default-flag.html#the-default-flag) flag.

Comment: i will try it tomorrow and accept your answer if it works, thanks a lot :)